# Aggregation framework need to match field value to group total

Tags: mongodb, match, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of students documents like:

```
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "Student" : "Sim",
        "Test1" : 59,
        "Test2" : 94,
        "Test3" : 81
}
{
        "_id" : 2,
        "Student" : "Sam",
        "Test1" : 60,
        "Test2" : 77,
        "Test3" : 81
}
```

I need to fine the name of students with Test1 score less thatn the total average of all tests of the entire class, using Aggregation frameworks.

I can get the total average in the following group section, but,,,

If

```
db.students.aggregate([
    {$project: { 
        Stu: '$Student',
        Test1: '$Test1',
        av: {$avg: ['$Test1', '$Test2', '$Test3']} 
    } },
    {$group: { _id: null, 
                totAvg: {$avg : '$av'} 
    }
 ]);
```

by then I lost the student and test1 to compare in a match section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$push + $filter`.

`$push` in `$group` stage to keep all the `test1` marks and `Student` names followed by `$filter` in `$project` stage to compare them against the total avg marks and keep the matching records.

You can wrap the `$filter` in a `$map` to project only student names.

```
db.students.aggregate([{
        $project: {
            Stu: '$Student',
            Test1: '$Test1',
            av: {
                $avg: ['$Test1', '$Test2', '$Test3']
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            studentTest1: {
                $push: {
                    "Student": "$Stu",
                    "Test1": "$Test1"
                }
            },
            totAvg: {
                $avg: '$av'
            }
        }
    },
    { $project:
     { lessthanAvgStudentNames:
        {
          $map:
             {
               input: {
                    $filter: {
                        input: "$studentTest1",
                        as: "resultf",
                        cond: {
                            $lt: ["$$resultf.Test1", "$totAvg"]
                        }
                    }
                },
               as: "resultm",
               in: "$$resultm.Student"
             }
        }
     }
   }
]);
```

Comment: thanks!!  that works!  ($filter, is new to me.,,, ).  How would I project only the sudent name?

Comment: You are welcome. Updated answer to include `$map` to to project only student names. links here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/ and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/